# Are there any good API design patterns where WRITES are separated from READS?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I'm writing a relatively simple web application made of three tiers:

1. Frontend: Very thin Controllers
2. Business Logic: Domain specific Services
3. Storage: Thin repository Classes

As suggested above, most of the business logic is in the Services tier 2.

As I write these classes, I find myself treating READ methods very differently to WRITE methods.

### READ Methods in the Service classes

For example, there aren't overly strict argument checks in the READ methods. A lot of the time, for simple reads, the Service methods are simply implementing the Repository methods almost with just one line.

### WRITE Methods in the Service classes

With the WRITE methods however I find myself doing way more argument checking, and business logic implementing. In fact in my service classes I have a dependency on a *Rules* class which only really gets used by my WRITE methods. There is biz logic in READS too, but logic is more strict on WRITES.

### Other *arguments* for possibly separating READS and WRITES

I also feel like when implementing a service class and looking for a method in a class, in my mind  first have an idea of whether I want to READ or WRITE, and then I look for the method.

I also feel like when looking for a method in a class, it seem messy to have to separate READS and WRITES by arbitrary method names that start with "Create", "Update", "Get", "Retrieve" etc. etc.

### Possible *problems* and, is it a good idea to separate?

I guess I'm looking for a **tried and tested pattern**. I could try implementing it myself, but I already feel like **there could be problems**, like **over complicating design**, or **circular references**, **repetition of logic**, eg. the READ class may depend on the WRITE class and vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are referring to Command Query Responsibility Segregation, [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)

Udi Dahan has a good article to start you off [here](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/12/09/clarified-cqrs/).

And MS Patterns and practices have a open source project http://cqrsjourney.github.com/ which is a pretty good example.

The drawbacks of this pattern is it can be over engineering, especially if you're writing a "relatively simple web application".

Udi writes another article on [When to avoid CQRS](http://www.udidahan.com/2011/04/22/when-to-avoid-cqrs/) and then again [Why you should be using CQRS almost everywhere](http://www.udidahan.com/2011/10/02/why-you-should-be-using-cqrs-almost-everywhere/) Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 great answer jflood, thanks. Yeah I had heard of CQRS but wasn't sure, also wanted to hear other opinions. Didn't know  about the MS project nor Udi's article, so will defo check that out and come back here and let you know. cheers!

Comment: Udi and Greg definitely overcomplicate CQRS.  The pattern itself is very simple, but it invariably gets mixed in with event sourcing and message queuing and all kinds of craziness.  I think this is the main reason why Martin Fowler is quick to fall back to the 'ReportingDatabase' pattern instead...

Comment: thanks gazarsgo... based on your comments, any suggestions on other patterns or do you think the CQRS pattern can work simplified, AND does it fit my requirements? cheers.

Comment: agreed, but note those last two articles by Udi are arguments for simplifying CQRS, they are long articles but worth the read.

Comment: You should post the information that is relevant inside the body of the text just in case the URL you are referencing ever gets broken for whatever reason.

Comment: Which, predictably enough, has happened.  The latest URL for the "Why you should be using CQRS..." is http://udidahan.com/2011/10/02/why-you-should-be-using-cqrs-almost-everywhere/ (but I shan't paste all the text therein: it's a long article)